# Exporting to PDF in emacs org-mode

Tags: pdf, emacs, latex, org-mode

I'm learning Emacs, and am currently focusing on orgmode, but am having some problems. I created a test file (named orgtest.org) with the following contents:

```
* h1
** s1
   1) l1
   2) l2
   3) l3
** s2
 * h2
```

And I made an attempt at exporting it to PDF for a first-time test with <kbd>C-x C-e p</kbd>. This did not work, so I tried M-x org-export-as-pdf, which also did not work. Both produced:

> Exporting to PDF...
>
> Exporting to LaTeX...
>
> Saving file /home/dodge/orgfile.tex...
>
> Wrote /home/dodge/orgfile.tex
>
> LaTeX export done, pushed to kill ring and clipboard
>
> Processing LaTeX file...
>
> (Shell command failed with code 127 and some error output) [2 times]
>
> Processing LaTeX file...done
>
> org-export-as-pdf: PDF file was not produced

What's the reason for this? I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 and Emacs 23.3.1

Comment: Without seeing the actual error messages it's hard to say. But I wonder if you've got a LaTeX environment installed. Try installing `texlive-full`.

Comment: @Chris It complains in the *Org PDF LaTeX Output* buffer that 
'/bin/bash: pdflatex: command not found'

Comment: I actually can't install texlive-full right now, as I'm currently in the process of upgrading to Ubuntu 12.10

Comment: Well, the [only package that provides `pdflatex` in the official 12.04 repository is `texlive-latex-base`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=pdflatex&mode=exactfilename&suite=precise&arch=any) (which is required by `texlive-full`). Installing that will be your easiest solution. (The `texlive-full` package should work on 12.10 as well; it's still supported in 13.10.)

Comment: Great, I'll update this question as soon as I can. Thanks.

Comment: Did you manage to get some variant of `texlive` installed, and did that solve your problem?

Comment: Oh, I totally forgot to update. Unfortunately for those interested, I was, for unrelated reasons, forced to reinstall Ubuntu. When I did, I just went with 12.10. For what it's worth, I installed emacs24.1.1 and texlive, and this was no longer a problem. I suspect you were right, Chris.